# How to use a method on a class object if method not defined in class c++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, methods, parameters

I have class `Pstring`

```
class Pstring
{
private:
   string palindrome;



public:
   Pstring() { palindrome = ""; }
   Pstring(string pal) { setString(pal); }
   void setString(string pal) { palindrome = pal; }
   string getPal() const { return palindrome; }


};
```

an object in my main method `Pstring palindrome(palin)` defined by

```
   string palin = "";

   cout << "Enter a palindrome:\n";
   getline(cin, palin);

   Pstring palindrome(palin);
```

and a current test method `bool isPalindrome(string pal)`defined as

```
bool isPalindrome(string pal)
{
   bool flag; 

   cout << "Do I have access to this?";
   cout << pal; 

   //code goes here to check for palindrome, return bool

}
```

I want to have my Pstring class object palindrome use the method isPalindrome in main, but when I try and invoke the method by using `palindrome.isPalinedrome(palin);` it doesn't seem to have access to the method.

What can I do to allow a method outside the class to be used by a class object in main?

Comment: Declare and define it, as an example. You cannot use something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Obviously.... I'm asking if there is a way.

Comment: @skypjack, what is declared but not defined? I apologize if the answer is obvious.

Comment: A class, a struct, a function, and so on, all of them must be both declared and defined. As a naïve example, `struct S;` is a valid statement, but there is no definition for `S` here, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `isPalinedrome()` method defined in the `Pstring` class, so you can't call it as `palindrome.isPalinedrome()` in your main code.

Instead of having `Pstring` try to call a function in your main code, you should move the palindrome logic into `Pstring`, and then the main code can ask `Pstring` when needed.

Try this:

```
class Pstring
{
private:
   string value;

public:
   Pstring() { }
   Pstring(const string &s) { setString(s); }
   void setString(const string &s) { value = s; }
   string getString() const { return value; }

   // add this...
   bool isPalindrome() const {
      //code goes here to check value for palindrome, return bool
   }
};
```

Then your main code can do this:

```
bool isPalindrome(const string &value)
{
   Pstring palindrome(value);
   return palindrome.isPalindrome();

   // or simply:
   // return Pstring(value).isPalindrome();
}

int main()
{
   string palin;

   cout << "Enter a palindrome:\n";
   getline(cin, palin);

   if (isPalindrome(palin)) {
      // do something ...
   } else {
      // do something else...
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Or this:

```
int main()
{
   string palin;

   cout << "Enter a palindrome:\n";
   getline(cin, palin);

   Pstring palindrome(palin);
   if (palindrome.isPalindrome()) {
      // do something ...
   } else {
      // do something else...
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add your test method into the class:

```
class Pstring
{
private:
   string palindrome;

public:
   // you don't need to initialize palindrome = "" (it's initialized by default)
   Pstring() {}

   // always pass strings as const reference unless you have
   // special reason to do it another way...
   Pstring(const string&  pal) { setString(pal); }
   void setString(const string& pal) { palindrome = pal; }
   string getPal() const { return palindrome; }

   bool isPalindrome() const // you don't have to pass string
   {
      bool flag; 

      cout << "Do I have access to this?";
      cout << palindrome; // please note this 

     //code goes here to check for palindrome, return bool

   }

};
```

And also please note the typo:
palindrome.isPalin**e**drome(palin);

Answer (score 0):

You can use function pointer to implement it:

declare class:

```
class Pstring{
private:
    string palindrome;
public:
    Pstring() { palindrome = ""; }
    Pstring(string pal) { setString(pal); }
    void setString(string pal) { palindrome = pal; }
    string getPal() const { return palindrome; }
    //add a function pointer member:
    bool(*isPalindrome) (string);
};
```

then define function:

```
 bool isPalindrome(string pal)
{
    bool flag;
    cout << "Do I have access to this?";
    cout << pal;

    //code goes here to check for palindrome, return bool
    return true;
}
```

now you can write code in main function:

```
string palin = "";

cout << "Enter a palindrome:\n";
getline(cin, palin);

Pstring palindrome(palin);
palindrome.isPalindrome = isPalindrome;//bind function
```

you can use the function by the object now:

```
palindrome.isPalindrome(palin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. what's the point to create this class? the only thing you need is the helper function isPalindrome(const std::string&). If you need some kinda scope protection, put it into a namespace may look better

Sorry but I have to say you are just make things complicated.

C++ is not java. If you don't use it, you should not pay for it.

Comment: I am a student, merely looking to learn the in's and out's of c++. I am not a professional. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I also like to keep main as clean as possible. Easier for me to read through my code.

Comment: Sorry mate. Was not in good mood yesterday. Please ignore my attitude.

Comment: All set mate :) Thanks a heap.